# Exception handling not required for lambda

Tags: java, exception, lambda

Imagine having this method:

```
public static File[] listDirectoryFiles(File directory) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (!directory.isDirectory())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter a directory");
    return directory.listFiles(File::isDirectory);
}
```

And then calling it this way:

```
File myDir = new File("C:\\Users\\bobby\\Downloads");
Arrays.asList(listDirectoryFiles(myDir)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Since the signature includes `throws IllegalArgumentException`, why is there no need to actually `try-catch` the call to `listDirectoryFiles` ?

Comment: Note that although your code uses lambdas there's no relation between them and the exception, not even in your code.

Comment: Good point! Not knowing that the confusion came from the fact that it was a `RuntimeException`, we actually thought it stemmed from the lambda's structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is subclass of [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>   Unchecked exceptions **do not need** to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.